# TTP conditional fields

Tags: python

I'm using TTP Template Text Parser to get information from a Huawei device.

In the output of the command I have this:

```
 ipv4-family vpn-instance VPN1
  import-route static
  import-route direct route-policy TESTE
 #
```

See that the import route, I may or may not have applied the configuration of a route-policy.

What I want is to build a list where, if there is a route-policy applied, only a new attribute is inserted, like this:

```
 import_routes: [
    {
        "protocol": "static"
    },
    {
        "protocol": "direct",
        "rp": "TESTE",
    }
 ]
```

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
  <group name="vpn_import_route*">
  import-route {{ protocol }}
  import-route {{ protocol }} route-policy {{ rp }} 
  </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

need to make sure that in your vpn_import_route group each line considered as a start of group, try this template modification:

```
  <group name="vpn_import_route*">
  import-route {{ protocol | _start_ }}
  import-route {{ protocol | _start_ }} route-policy {{ rp }} 
  </group>
```

This documentation goes in details of parsing varying output - https://ttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#how-to-match-several-variations-of-slightly-changing-output